# put zeros make it 4 digits

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Put zeros make it four digits before the numbers with less than four digits.
I have an dataframe like this;

```
import pandas as pd

data={'Name':['Karan','Rohit','Sahil','Aryan','Zeyd'],'number':[1,0,1111,111,11]}

df=pd.dataframe(data)
```

and I want to obtain this output:

| Name | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| Karan | 0001 |
| Rohit | 0000 |
| Sahil | 1111 |
| Aryan | 0111 |
| Zeyd | 0011 |

Comment: @TheMyth your link is for [tag:R]

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, one approach is to use [`str.zfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html)

```
df["Filled"] = df["number"].astype("string").str.zfill(4)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
    Name  number Filled
0  Karan       1   0001
1  Rohit       0   0000
2  Sahil    1111   1111
3  Aryan     111   0111
4   Zeyd      11   0011
```

Answer (score 0):

1 possible solution:

```
import pandas as pd

data={'Name':['Karan','Rohit','Sahil','Aryan','Zeyd'],'number':[1,0,1111,111,11]}

counter = 0
for i in data['number']:
    new = str(i).zfill(4)
    data['number'][counter] = new
    counter += 1

df= pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
```

Might not be the best answer, since I've never worked with Pandas before, but it works